# Using a Pandas dataframe index as values for x-axis in matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I have time series in a Pandas `dateframe` with a number of columns which I'd like to plot. Is there a way to set the x-axis to always use the index from a `dateframe`?
When I use the `.plot()` method from Pandas the x-axis is formatted correctly however I when I pass my dates and the column(s) I'd like to plot directly to matplotlib the graph doesn't plot correctly. Thanks in advance.

```
plt.plot(site2.index.values, site2['Cl'])
plt.show()
```

[image: output]

FYI: `site2.index.values` produces this (I've cut out the middle part for brevity):

```
array([
    '1987-07-25T12:30:00.000000000+0200',
    '1987-07-25T16:30:00.000000000+0200',
    '2010-08-13T02:00:00.000000000+0200',
    '2010-08-31T02:00:00.000000000+0200',
    '2010-09-15T02:00:00.000000000+0200'
], 
dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems the issue was that I had `.values`. Without it (i.e. `site2.index`) the graph displays [correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22LkY.jpg)

Answer (score 11):

You can use `plt.xticks` to set the x-axis

try:

```
plt.xticks( site2['Cl'], site2.index.values ) # location, labels
plt.plot( site2['Cl'] )
plt.show()
```

see the documentation for more details: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there some way to use `matplotlib` to select a 'sensible' scale? For instance with the Pandas `.plot` method it will select days, months or years for the x-axis as appropriate. If I understand the documentation correctly it seems that for every data point of `site2['Cl']` there'll be an `xtick` which will be far too many for my data set.

Also I think that something might be wrong with my date because my new graph looks like [this](http://imgur.com/s5cQ8zz)

Answer (score 2):

That's Builtin Right Into To `plot() method`

You can use `yourDataFrame.plot(use_index=True)` to use the DataFrame Index On X-Axis.

The "use_index=True" sets the DataFrame Index on the X-Axis.

Read More Here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
x=yourDataFrame.index.values
```

which will use the values of the indices of yourDataFrame on the x-axis

Answer (score -1):

you want to use matplotlib to select a 'sensible' scale just like me, there is one way can solve this question. using a Pandas dataframe index as values for x-axis in matplotlib plot. Code:

```
ax = plt.plot(site2['Cl'])
x_ticks = ax.get_xticks() # use matplotlib default xticks
x_ticks = list(filter(lambda x: x in range(len(site2)), x_ticks))
ax.set_xticklabels([' '] + site2.index.iloc[x_ticks].to_list())
```