# time series of yahoo finance data from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have stock price data from yahoo saved in a dictionary of dataframes `price_data`, and I would like to generate some basic time series plots with this.

I've tried using a couple of other answers on here, however I've ended up with some messy results. For instance the x axis not displaying correctly from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356881/using-a-pandas-dataframe-index-as-values-for-x-axis-in-matplotlib-plot).

*What is the neatest way to generate a time series of the `Adj Close` column from the dataframe `price_data['AAPL']`, and save the result to a png file?*

Here is some info on the structure of this dataframe:

```
In [41]: type(price_data['AAPL'])
Out[41]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In [42]: list(price_data['AAPL'].columns.values)
Out[42]: ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close']

In [45]: type(price_data['AAPL'].index)
Out[45]: pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex
```

Comment: What if you just do `price_data['AAPL']['Adj Close'].plot()`?

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn; I knew there had to be something simple. Is saving the result to a png also quite easy? plt.savefig('foo.png') is just giving me an empty image

Comment: Just using `savefig` works for me.  What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I've got it working, I wasn't referencing the right module. It needed plt.pyplot.savefig(file_name). Thanks =)

Comment: You probably did `import matplotlib as plt`.  Usually `plt` is used when people do `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Date column to Timestamps and set it as the index.

```
In [829]: temp
Out[829]: 
       Date   Open   High    Low  Close    Volume    Adj  
0  19/10/11  27.37  27.47  27.01  27.13  42880000  27.13
1  18/10/11  26.94  27.40  26.80  27.31  52487900  27.31
2  17/10/11  27.11  27.42  26.85  26.98  39433400  26.98
3  14/10/11  27.31  27.50  27.02  27.27  50947700  27.27

In [830]: temp['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(temp['Date'])

In [831]: temp
Out[831]: 
        Date   Open   High    Low  Close    Volume    Adj
0 2011-10-19  27.37  27.47  27.01  27.13  42880000  27.13
1 2011-10-18  26.94  27.40  26.80  27.31  52487900  27.31
2 2011-10-17  27.11  27.42  26.85  26.98  39433400  26.98
3 2011-10-14  27.31  27.50  27.02  27.27  50947700  27.27
```

And, this will get you the plot:

```
In [832]: temp.set_index('Date')['Adj'].plot()
```