# Python 3.0 Pandas and Matplotlib: bar() and other matplotlib plots not accepting string dataframe index as x-axis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, data-science

The following code is to get the total number of women who got rejected and admitted in a particular school year:

```
query1=All_Females_count[['Admit','Freq']].groupby('Admit').sum()
print(query1)
query1.set_index(data.Admit.unique())
query1.plot(kind='bar')
```

The above code seems to work okay and give me a bar plot as expected. However, the code below does not:

```
 plt.bar(query1.index,query1.Freq)
 plt.show()
```

All_Females_count dataframe is as given below:

```
    Admit   Gender  Dept    Freq
2   Admitted    Female  A   89
3   Rejected    Female  A   19
6   Admitted    Female  B   17
7   Rejected    Female  B   8
10  Admitted    Female  C   202
11  Rejected    Female  C   391
14  Admitted    Female  D   131
15  Rejected    Female  D   244
18  Admitted    Female  E   94
19  Rejected    Female  E   299
22  Admitted    Female  F   24
23  Rejected    Female  F   317
```

Can anyone tell me why? Is the only way around this is to use labels with numeric data?

I also found this discussion thread:https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2516/
on the same topic.

This is a very similar question. However, it did not address my problem:[Using a Pandas dataframe index as values for x-axis in matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356881/using-a-pandas-dataframe-index-as-values-for-x-axis-in-matplotlib-plot)

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib` generally expects numerical values for its x-axis. As [the documentation for `plt.bar()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20bar#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) states (emphasis mine):

> x : sequence of **scalars**
>
> the x coordinates of the bars.

A fairly simple way to reproduce the behavior of `pandas` is to call `bar()` with a list from 0 to the number of values in your index, then replace the ticks labels with the actual content of the index.

```
plt.bar(range(len(query1.index)),query1.Freq)
plt.xticks(range(len(query1.index)), query1.index)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Glad to hear. If you feel your question has been solved, consider accepting one of the answers using the green tick line to close that thread

Comment: I absolutely would have, except I am very new to Stackoverflow :(

Answer (score 0):

To get labels on bar graphs you need to supply numeric values to the first argument. The labels can be set using the `tick_labels` argument.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = list("ABC")
y = [1,3,4]

plt.bar(range(len(y)), y, tick_label=x)

plt.show()
```